# Android HTML like Textwrapping in TextView

Tags: android, html, text, word-wrap

Is it possible to wrap text in android as we do in HTML? For example, in HTML when have have an image and some text on its left or right side. When the text increases to the size of image, it starts from the beginning of the next line. like

[image]

There is a single textview and an ImageView on its left.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the content inside is set to String, the layout of
the file it textview We know that to make parsing and display TextView
 Html code. You can use the

```
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml (source); tv.setText (text);
```

To achieve this with a simple and convenient. However, also shows how
 to make TextView Html in  node images?
 We can see fromHtml another reconstruction:

```
`fromHtml (String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)`
```

Can make to achieve what ImageGetter picture shows:

```
ImageGetter imgGetter = new Html.ImageGetter () {
              @ Override
              public Drawable getDrawable (String source) {
                    Drawable drawable = null;
                    drawable = Drawable.createFromPath (source); 
                    // Or fetch it from the URL
                    // Important
                    drawable.setBounds (0, 0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth (), drawable
                                  . getIntrinsicHeight ());
                    return drawable;
              } };
```

As TagHandler, we need to use here, can pass null. I think he has to help you。 my wibsite is

http://onmyfree.sinaapp.com.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually my question was how to wrap textview text around the imageview? I have a single imageview and there is a single textview on its right side whose text is to be wrapped around the imageview.

Comment: your link is break,can you modify it?

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean, then I suggest you write your own view, encapsulates it into a component, so should be able to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I foud a new way to slove it,it's use ImageSpan of TextView ,like this

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);

SpannableString spanStr = new SpannableString("掌声那历史的房间里是副经理撒旦法阿斯顿及福利费是到发顺丰");
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(this, R.drawable.a);
spanStr.setSpan(imageSpan, 3, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(spanStr);

setContentView(tv);

enter code here
```

this website will help u ,[linkToWebsite](http://orgcent.com/android-imagespan-view-html/)